# How not to hyphenate the last word of a paragraph

Tags: hyphenation

The LaTeX hyphenation is very good. However, how to not apply any hyphen to the last word of every paragraph? Of course, one can use the `\mbox{last word}` combination, but this is too complicated.

Comment: ??? This never should happen!

Comment: An example of a paragraph in which it happens?

Comment: @Bernard - Actually, it can happen -- but, realistically, only if the paragraph is fairly short and the final word of the paragraph is very long.

Answer (score 11):

(revised answer after receiving comments by Enrico and Gustavo)

Both Plain-TeX and LaTeX provide the following default setting:

```
\finalhyphendemerits=5000
```

This parameter comes into play if the second-to-last line of a paragraph ends with a discretionary hyphen. Changing this setting to  `\finalhyphendemerits=200000`, say, seriously increases the penalty associated with a discretionary at the end of the second-to-last line of a paragraph -- making it (much) less likely that such a discretionary will occur.

However, if the final word of the paragraph happens to be something like "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious", TeX may still insert a discretionary hyphen in that word even if `\finalhyphendemerits=1000000` is in effect, since failing to hyphenate the word could make the paragraph look (even) worse.

---

Here's an MWE. Observe that the first paragraph, which allows hyphenation of the final instance of "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious" even though `\finalhyphendemerits=1000000` is in force, looks a whole lot better than the second paragraph, in which the final word cannot be hyphenated because of the presence of the `\mbox` wrapper.

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article} % insert a "slug" at overfull lines
\newcommand\super{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious }
\begin{document}
\finalhyphendemerits=1000000
\noindent
\super\super\super

\noindent
\super\super\mbox{\super}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Demerits are in the order of badness squared; there's no concept of infinite demerits

Comment: @egreg - OK, let me fix the loose language...

Comment: OOC, where do people learn this stuff? Is there like *The TeX Standard for Dummies" or something?  I don't even know how I would begin to find out this information besides internet Q&A sites.

Comment: @Mico The fact is that 10000 is not so bigger than 5000; maybe 200000

Comment: @egreg - No quibble about 10000 not being all that much larger than 5000. Separately, are you saying that it's possible to set the demerit to, say, 200000?

Comment: @user1717828 - Chapter 14 ("How TeX breaks paragraphs into lines") of Knuth's *TeXbook* and Chapter 19 (title: "Line breaking") of Eijkhout's *TeX by Topic* are probably the canonical references for line-breaking matters.

Comment: @Mico: Yes, it is possible to set a demerit to 200000: as egreg has already recalled, demerits are in units of badness *squared*.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti - Thanks. I've updated my answer to reflect this information.